# redirect output from stdout to a string?

Tags: c, redirect, stdout

in C
i want to redirect the output of a process from stdout to write to a "shared memory segment" which can be thought of as a char array or a string with a pointer
i know that there is dup2 but it takes file discriptors as argument not a pointer to an array.  is there any way to redirect it to a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char string[SIZE];
freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout);
setbuf(stdout, string);
```

see [freopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) and [setbuf](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) for their definitions

Comment: Note that the buffer size MUST be exactly `BUFSIZ` in bytes! If it's smaller, you'll have a buffer overflow vulnerability, and if it's larger, it will never be used. This solution will not work if you want to buffer more than BUFSIZ bytes.

Comment: how to undo this ? Is it need to undo it ?

Comment: Windows equivalent please?

Answer (score 5):

This should work on UNIX systems:

```
// set buffer size, SIZE
SIZE = 255;

char buffer[SIZE];
freopen("/dev/null", "a", stdout);
setbuf(stdout, buffer);
printf("This will be stored in the buffer");
freopen ("/dev/tty", "a", stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks, searched for ages trying to find how to do this. A few points !) requires c99 or later, 2) I had to set buffer[SIZE]={0} to avoid trailing garbage and 3) also works on Windows if you replace "/dev/tty" with "CON".

Answer (score 0):

You could write to a pipe, and read from it into shared memory (that is, if you can't use the pipe *instead* of the string in shared memory).

Comment: i have two different processes (not a child and a parent) so i cant do pipe between them. right?

Answer (score 0):

with [shm_open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) you can have a file descriptor pointing to a shared memory and pass it to dup2 function as below:

```
int fd = shm_open("shm-name", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
fprintf(stdout, "This is string is gonna be printed on shared memory");
```

And after all seek the shared memory to the beginning (with lseek read it and save it to a string; But be careful

Also you can find an example of buffering into pipe in [Here](https://github.com/pouyanh/isolated-iostream/blob/master/src/main.c#L58)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a simple redirection of stdout to a memory string, just do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PATH_MAX 1000

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    fp = popen("ls ", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)  return 0;


    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
        printf("\nTest=> %s", path);

    status = pclose(fp);
}
```