# Reroute stdout to string

Tags: stdout, d, dmd

OK, so here's what I'm trying to do :

- A portion of my program outputs text to console
- For unittest purposes, I'd like to be able to get that output into a string, so that I can use it in an `assert` check.

How is that possible?

---

**NOTE:**

Guys, sorry if I mislead you. I'm looking for a solution in D.

Comment: on linux maybe using `$(./executable)` in the bash?

Comment: Which platform are you on linux/windows?

Comment: You could create a custom output function that concatenates to a string and then outputs data. Like a custom printf or a custom istream if you prefer C++

Comment: perhaps you need [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/).

Comment: @al-Acme Close... OSX. lol. However, I'm not looking for a platform-specific solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect output from stdout to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428406/redirect-output-from-stdout-to-a-string)

Comment: The easiest way to do something like this in standard C is to use `fprintf(stream, ...)` where "stream" is stdout in the normal case and a text file in the test case.

Comment: @alAcme and Lundin, this is a D Programming Language question.

Comment: @BobMalooga It's not a C-related question, this one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using pipes and threads (which, unlike the suggested duplicate, is not limited to a predefined buffer size or risks a buffer overflow vulnerabillity):

1. Create a pipe using [`std.process.pipe`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#.pipe)
2. Set `stdout` to the pipe's write end (back it up first)
3. Spawn a thread which would read from the pipe's read end and append output to a string, until the pipe is closed
4. Execute the task at hand
5. Close the write end of the pipe
6. Restore the old value of `stdout`
7. Wait for the thread to finish execution
8. Use the buffer created by the thread

I have some similar code, albeit in the other direction (asynchronous writing as opposed to reading), [here](https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/sys/cmd.d#L63-L77) and [here](https://github.com/CyberShadow/ae/blob/master/sys/file.d#L637-L673).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just think I've found a working way myself :

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
import std.file;

//

string getOutput()
{
     auto initialStdout = stdout;

     // Redirect output to file
     string tmpfile = "tmp/test.out";
     stdout.open(tmpfile, "wt");

     //
     // Do whatever you want to,
     // that generates some output
     //

     stdout = initialStdout; // Restore stdout to what it was

     return to!string(std.file.read(tmpfile)); // Return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [std.process.executeShell](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#.executeShell) . The example from the Phobos documentation is good enough for you to do what you need.